# Barchart doesn't show my values when filtered

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I don't know if I'm using the correct way of filtering a barchart, or even if my code is properly written.

But I have  problem, when I open my dashboard, I have 3 charts, one of the piecharts can filter the barchart, and depending on which was selected, the barchart only shows the piechart selected, otherwise shows all.

My problem is when I filter those, I'm getting the correct filter, but I can't get the labels to appear, they just appear when I got only one, for example if I have 1Yellow, 15 Reds, its only a bar to show, but it only shows the label for the yellow one, but if yellow2 and 15 reds, it doesn't show any of them.

It should be a easy fix, I just can't see where is the error.

```
ArrayList<Integer> colors_to_add_type = new ArrayList<>();
                            ArrayList<Integer> colors_to_add_type_MINOR = new ArrayList<>();
                            ArrayList<Integer> colors_to_add_type_MEDIUM = new ArrayList<>();
                            ArrayList<Integer> colors_to_add_type_MAJOR = new ArrayList<>();
                            ArrayList<Integer> colors_to_add_type_OTHER = new ArrayList<>();
                            Iterator<String> defects_colors_keys;
                            defects_colors_keys = colors_type.keys();
                            while (defects_colors_keys.hasNext()){
                                String key = defects_colors_keys.next();
                                Log.e("COLOR_KEY", "onResponse: " + key );
                                int to_add = Color.parseColor(colors_type.getString(key));
                                int to_add_MINOR = Color.parseColor("#00FF00");
                                int to_add_MEDIUM = Color.parseColor("#FFFF00");
                                int to_add_MAJOR = Color.parseColor("#FF0000");
                                int to_add_OTHER = Color.parseColor("#800080");
                                Log.e("COLOR_NAME", "onResponse: " + colors_type.getString(key));
                                colors_to_add_type.add(to_add);
                                colors_to_add_type_MAJOR.add(to_add_MAJOR);
                                colors_to_add_type_MEDIUM.add(to_add_MEDIUM);
                                colors_to_add_type_MINOR.add(to_add_MINOR);
                                colors_to_add_type_OTHER.add(to_add_OTHER);
                            }
                            List<LegendEntry> legends_type = new ArrayList<>();
                            List<LegendEntry> legends_type_MINOR = new ArrayList<>();
                            List<LegendEntry> legends_type_MEDIUM = new ArrayList<>();
                            List<LegendEntry> legends_type_MAJOR = new ArrayList<>();
                            List<LegendEntry> legends_type_OTHER = new ArrayList<>();
                                type_of_defects = by_type.keys();
                                int c = 0;
                                if(!map_defects_by_type_count.isEmpty()){
                                    map_defects_by_type_count.clear();
                                }
                                Log.e("DEFECTS", defects_list.toString());
                                Log.e("DEFECTS",String.valueOf(defects_list.size()));
                                while(type_of_defects.hasNext()) {
                                    String key = type_of_defects.next();
                                    Log.e("DEFECTS_type", key.toString());
                                    map_defects_by_type_count.put(key, by_type.getInt(key));
                                    map_get_defect_type.put(c, key);
                                    LegendEntry legendEntry = new LegendEntry();
                                    legendEntry.label = key;
                                    legendEntry.formColor = colors_to_add_type.get(c);
                                    legends_type.add(legendEntry);
                                    arr_by_type.add(new BarEntry((float)c + 1, (int)by_type.getInt(key), (String)key));
                                    c++;
                                    for (int i = 0; i < defects_list.size(); i++){
                                        if (defects_list.get(i).getStringProperty("defect").equals(key)){
                                            if (defects_list.get(i).getStringProperty("criticality").equals("MAJOR")){
                                                arr_by_type_MAJOR.add(new BarEntry((float)c +1, (int)by_type.getInt(key), (String)key));
                                                legends_type_MAJOR.add(legendEntry);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            if (defects_list.get(i).getStringProperty("criticality").equals("MEDIUM")){
                                                arr_by_type_MEDIUM.add(new BarEntry((float)c +1 , (int)by_type.getInt(key), (String)key));
                                                legends_type_MEDIUM.add(legendEntry);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            if (defects_list.get(i).getStringProperty("criticality").equals("MINOR")){
                                                arr_by_type_MINOR.add(new BarEntry((float)c +1, (int)by_type.getInt(key), (String)key));
                                                legends_type_MINOR.add(legendEntry);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            if (defects_list.get(i).getStringProperty("criticality").equals("OTHER")){
                                                arr_by_type_OTHER.add(new BarEntry((float)c +1, (int)by_type.getInt(key), (String)key));
                                                legends_type_OTHER.add(legendEntry);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                TOTAL_DEFECTS = TOTAL_BY_CRIT;
                            if(TOTAL_BY_CRIT != 0){
                                if(MAJOR != 0){
                                    major_percent =  (float) MAJOR / TOTAL_BY_CRIT;
                                }
                                if(MEDIUM != 0){
                                    medium_percent =  (float) MEDIUM / TOTAL_BY_CRIT;
                                }
                                if(MINOR != 0){
                                    minor_percent = (float) MINOR / TOTAL_BY_CRIT;
                                }
                                if(OTHER != 0){
                                    other_percent = (float) OTHER / TOTAL_BY_CRIT;
                                }
                            }

                            TOTAL_SOURCE = TOTAL_H_M;
                            if(TOTAL_H_M != 0){
                                if(HUMAN != 0){
                                    human_percent = (float) HUMAN / TOTAL_H_M;
                                }
                                if(MACHINE != 0){
                                    machine_percent = (float) MACHINE / TOTAL_H_M;
                                }
                            }
                            arr_by_defect.add(new PieEntry(MAJOR, "MAJOR"));
                            arr_by_defect.add(new PieEntry(MEDIUM, "MEDIUM"));
                            arr_by_defect.add(new PieEntry(MINOR, "MINOR"));
                            arr_by_defect.add(new PieEntry(OTHER, "OTHER"));
                            arr_by_source.add(new PieEntry(HUMAN, "HUMAN"));
                            arr_by_source.add(new PieEntry(MACHINE, "MACHINE"));
                            dataSet_by_defect = new PieDataSet(arr_by_defect, "");
                            dataSet_by_source = new PieDataSet(arr_by_source, "");
                            dataSet_by_type = new BarDataSet(arr_by_type, "");
                            dataSet_by_type_MAJOR = new BarDataSet(arr_by_type_MAJOR, "");
                            dataSet_by_type_MEDIUM = new BarDataSet(arr_by_type_MEDIUM, "");
                            dataSet_by_type_MINOR = new BarDataSet(arr_by_type_MINOR, "");
                            dataSet_by_type_OTHER = new BarDataSet(arr_by_type_OTHER, "");
                            //GET THE COLORS
                            String colorMajor = colors.getString("MAJOR");
                            String colorMedium = colors.getString("MEDIUM");
                            String colorMinor = colors.getString("MINOR");
                            String colorOther = colors.getString("OTHER");
                            String colorHuman = human_machine_colors.getString("human");
                            String colorMachine = human_machine_colors.getString("machine");
                            final int[] sliceColors = {Color.parseColor(colorMajor), Color.parseColor(colorMedium), Color.parseColor(colorMinor), Color.parseColor(colorOther)};
                            ArrayList<Integer> colorsSet = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int color : sliceColors){
                                colorsSet.add(color);
                            }
                            Log.e("COLORS_TO ADD", "MAJOR" + colorMajor);
                            Log.e("COLORS_TO ADD", "MEDIUM" + colorMedium);
                            Log.e("COLORS_TO ADD", "MINOR" + colorMinor);
                            Log.e("COLORS_TO ADD", "OTHER" + colorOther);
                            dataSet_by_defect.setColors(colorsSet);
                            final int[] sliceColors_hm = {Color.parseColor(colorHuman), Color.parseColor(colorMachine)};
                            ArrayList<Integer> colorsSet_hm = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int color : sliceColors_hm){
                                colorsSet_hm.add(color);
                            }
                            dataSet_by_source.setColors(colorsSet_hm);
                            dataSet_by_type.setColors(colors_to_add_type);
                            dataSet_by_type_MINOR.setColors(colors_to_add_type_MINOR);
                            dataSet_by_type_MEDIUM.setColors(colors_to_add_type_MEDIUM);
                            dataSet_by_type_MAJOR.setColors(colors_to_add_type_MAJOR);
                            dataSet_by_type_OTHER.setColors(colors_to_add_type_OTHER);
                            dataSet_by_type.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
                            dataSet_by_type_MINOR.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
                            dataSet_by_type_MEDIUM.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
                            dataSet_by_type_MAJOR.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
                            dataSet_by_type_OTHER.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);


                            final PieData data_defect = new PieData(dataSet_by_defect);
                            final PieData data_source = new PieData(dataSet_by_source);
                            final BarData data_type = new BarData(dataSet_by_type);
                            final BarData data_type_MINOR = new BarData(dataSet_by_type_MINOR);
                            final BarData data_type_MEDIUM = new BarData(dataSet_by_type_MEDIUM);
                            final BarData data_type_MAJOR = new BarData(dataSet_by_type_MAJOR);
                            final BarData data_type_OTHER = new BarData(dataSet_by_type_OTHER);
                            data_type.setDrawValues(true);
                            data_type_MAJOR.setDrawValues(true);
                            data_type_MEDIUM.setDrawValues(true);
                            data_type_MINOR.setDrawValues(true);
                            data_type_OTHER.setDrawValues(true);

                            data_defect.setDrawValues(false);
                            data_source.setDrawValues(false);
                            //data_type.setBarWidth(.75f);
                            piechart_defects.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
                            piechart_defects.setHoleColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                            piechart_defects.setDrawEntryLabels(false);
                            piechart_defects.setDrawMarkers(false);
                            piechart_defects.setCenterText(String.valueOf(TOTAL_DEFECTS) + " TOTAL");
                            piechart_defects.setCenterTextSize(10);
                            piechart_defects.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
                            Legend l_defect = piechart_defects.getLegend();
                            l_defect.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.TOP);
                            l_defect.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
                            l_defect.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.VERTICAL);
                            l_defect.setDrawInside(false);
                            l_defect.setEnabled(true);
                            l_defect.setFormSize(4f);
                            l_defect.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            l_defect.setTextSize(.5f);
                            piechart_source.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
                            piechart_source.setDrawEntryLabels(false);
                            piechart_source.setHoleColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                            piechart_source.setDrawMarkers(false);
                            piechart_source.setCenterText(String.valueOf(TOTAL_SOURCE) + " TOTAL");
                            piechart_source.setCenterTextSize(10);
                            piechart_source.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
                            piechart_source.setTransparentCircleRadius(10f);
                            Legend l_source = piechart_source.getLegend();
                            l_source.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.TOP);
                            l_source.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
                            l_source.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.VERTICAL);
                            l_source.setDrawInside(false);
                            l_source.setEnabled(true);
                            l_source.setFormSize(4f);
                            l_source.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            l_source.setTextSize(.5f);
                            dataSet_by_type.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            dataSet_by_type_MAJOR.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            dataSet_by_type_MEDIUM.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            dataSet_by_type_MINOR.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            dataSet_by_type_OTHER.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                            dataSet_by_type.setValueTextSize(7f);
                            dataSet_by_type_MINOR.setValueTextSize(7f);
                            dataSet_by_type_MEDIUM.setValueTextSize(7f);
                            dataSet_by_type_MAJOR.setValueTextSize(7f);
                            dataSet_by_type_OTHER.setValueTextSize(7f);

                            data_type.setBarWidth(.5f);

                            data_type.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
                                @Override
                                public String getBarLabel(BarEntry barEntry) {
                                    int barEntryY = (int) barEntry.getY();

                                    return (String)barEntry.getData() + "  " + "(" + String.valueOf(barEntryY) + ")";
                                }
                            });


                        Legend l_type_MAJOR = barchart_type.getLegend();
                        l_type_MAJOR.setCustom(legends_type_MAJOR);
                        l_type_MAJOR.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
                        l_type_MAJOR.setDrawInside(true);
                        data_type_MAJOR.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
                            @Override
                            public String getBarLabel(BarEntry barEntry) {
                                int barEntryY = (int) barEntry.getY();
                                return (String)barEntry.getData() + "  " + "(" + String.valueOf(barEntryY) + ")";
                            }
                        });
                        data_type_MAJOR.setBarWidth(.5f);

                        Legend l_type_OTHER = barchart_type.getLegend();
                        l_type_OTHER.setCustom(legends_type_OTHER);
                        l_type_OTHER.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
                        l_type_OTHER.setDrawInside(true);
                        data_type_OTHER.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
                            @Override
                            public String getBarLabel(BarEntry barEntry) {
                                int barEntryY = (int) barEntry.getY();
                                return (String)barEntry.getData() + "  " + "(" + String.valueOf(barEntryY) + ")";
                            }
                        });
                        data_type_OTHER.setBarWidth(.5f);

                        Legend l_type_MINOR = barchart_type.getLegend();
                        l_type_MINOR.setCustom(legends_type_MINOR);
                        l_type_MINOR.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
                        l_type_MINOR.setDrawInside(true);
                        data_type_MINOR.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
                            @Override
                            public String getBarLabel(BarEntry barEntry) {
                                int barEntryY = (int) barEntry.getY();

                                return (String)barEntry.getData() + "  " + "(" + String.valueOf(barEntryY) + ")";
                            }
                        });

                        Legend l_type_MEDIUM = barchart_type.getLegend();
                        l_type_MEDIUM.setCustom(legends_type_MEDIUM);
                        l_type_MEDIUM.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
                        l_type_MEDIUM.setDrawInside(true);
                        data_type_MEDIUM.setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
                            @Override
                            public String getBarLabel(BarEntry barEntry) {
                                int barEntryY = (int) barEntry.getY();

                                return (String)barEntry.getData() + "  " + "(" + String.valueOf(barEntryY) + ")";
                            }
                        });








                            barchart_type.setRenderer(new MyRenderer(barchart_type, barchart_type.getAnimator(), barchart_type.getViewPortHandler()));

                            Legend l_type = barchart_type.getLegend();
                            l_type.setCustom(legends_type);
                            l_type.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
                            l_type.setDrawInside(true);
                            piechart_defects.setData(data_defect);
                            piechart_defects.invalidate();
                            piechart_source.setData(data_source);
                            piechart_source.invalidate();

                            barchart_type.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(false);
                            barchart_type.setScaleEnabled(false);
                            barchart_type.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
                            barchart_type.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
                            barchart_type.getXAxis().setDrawLabels(false);
                            barchart_type.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
                            barchart_type.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
                            barchart_type.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
                            barchart_type.setBorderColor(Color.BLACK);
                            barchart_type.setDrawBorders(false);


                            barchart_type.setData(data_type);
                            barchart_type.setMinimumHeight(arr_by_type.size()*250);
                            barchart_type.invalidate();
                            Log.e("INFO BAR", data_type.toString());


                        piechart_defects.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
                                String value = String.valueOf((int)h.getY());
                                String toShow = "";
                                if(h.getX() == 0){
                                    toShow = " MAJOR \n" + value;
                                    chartSelectedDefect = "MAJOR";
                                    barchart_type.setData(data_type_MAJOR);
                                }else if(h.getX() == 1){
                                    toShow = " MEDIUM \n" + value;
                                    chartSelectedDefect = "MEDIUM";
                                    barchart_type.setData(data_type_MEDIUM);
                                    barchart_type.invalidate();
                                }else if(h.getX() == 2){
                                    toShow = " MINOR \n" + value ;
                                    chartSelectedDefect = "MINOR";
                                    barchart_type.setData(data_type_MINOR);
                                }else if(h.getX() == 3){
                                    toShow = " OTHER \n" + value;
                                    chartSelectedDefect = "OTHER";
                                    barchart_type.setData(data_type_OTHER);
```

How it appears when I show all:

[image]

[image: How it appears on filtered. It should keep the size of the bar as well but it doesn't:]

[image]

[image: The yellow one appears the label, I don't know why...]

Comment: Please take the time to create a [minimum complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that someone else could run and see the same issue. When I try a simple bar chart with its data set toggled by a switch (like you are doing here) it works fine.

Comment: @TylerV i found the problem, it seems like my graph is drawing correctly, what is happening is, sometimes my graph is shifting towards left, and i only see a fracion of my bars, its some setting not working good, maybe im setting the minimum height but as my graph is turned in other direction i have to work with the width. But thanks for the example anyway, i will give a look.

Comment: Probably need to adjust your axis min and max values as you change the data.

Comment: @TylerV i dont know whats happening, because i have a chart who has a bar with 122 errors, so it should disformat the barchart too, and it dont happen. Can't see where is the error, cant it be a bug ?

Comment: Nobody can debug your code for you without seeing it - you have to make a complete example (ideally as small as possible) that someone else could run to see the same issue if you want help.

Comment: @TylerV i fixed my problem, now i got a diferent one, what is the setting where i set the minimum scale on my Y bar. like my bar is starting from 0 now, but wheni have like 20 problems, the bar have the values like 1, 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ... but if i only have 5 problems, the values go for 0.5, 1 , 1.5, 2 ... or even less. how do i set the minimun to be 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ... ?  sorry but i cant explain it better

Comment: Ok, now i fixed it... Thanks for your help... Im just going to close this. Thanks for your help.